# JavaScript multiple predicates body not evaluated

Tags: javascript, predicate

I‘d like to create an array (or any kind of structure) which holds multiple predicates so I can apply it to another array which holds my testing-objects.

My sample is..

```
const predicate = (obj) => obj % 2 === 0;
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(predicate));
```

…which works fine.

However this is just one predicate so I tried to do something like this…

```
const predicate = (obj) => {
obj % 2 === 0
};
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(predicate));
```

..to see if I could do bit more in the body of the arrow function.
This however lets to nothing. In fact not even the one condition is applied successfully.

I found the callback definition and the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) for it but it doesn’t help me.

Isn’t there an way to implement this very easily so the next developer which looks at it doesn’t have to think bout it too long?

I thought of sth. like

```
const predicates = (obj) => [
obj % 2 === 0,
obj > 2
];
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(predicates.forEach));
```

But the syntax isn’t supported. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: You forgot to return anything from the second `predicate`

Comment: Are you looking for `const predicates = (obj) => obj % 2 === 0 || obj > 2`?

Comment: That `forEach` approach seems like a step in a random direction syntactically.  Within your `predicate` function you can execute whatever code you like, but it needs to return a (truthy or falsy) value for `filter` to use it.  But within that function you can loop through other predicate functions if you like, returning whatever result you want based on your logic.  (e.g. if you want it to match *every* condition vs. *any* condition)

Comment: @0stone0 i didn’t return anything in the first block and it works.. and not - I don’t want to concatenate Avery condition by logical operations. They should be available in a structure to access them (this isn’t in the code sample. since it didn’t addressed my problem i simplified)

Comment: @David I got that - however in the working example the Boolean return seems to be implicitly. What’s the difference of putting {} around the body?

Comment: Nvm - just read the robot link above